# Error al obtener el value de la opción elegida del radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito obtener con jquery el value de la opción elegida del radio button, al inspeccionar la pagina por consola muestra el siguiente error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: "input:radio[name='option']:checked".val is not a function".

Aca mi código:

```js
  function Send() {

    var option = $("input:radio[name='option']:checked".val());
    alert(option);
    
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="bookName" /> Buscar por nombre de libro
 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="idBook" /> Buscar por ID
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Send();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>Buscar</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: mejor usa un id y llama con '#option'. Pero aparte de eso, el checked es para el objeto en sí, ósease, una vez ya teniendo el Elemento HTML haz elemento.checked Lo cual te regresará un valor booleano si son dos, el regresar false indicará que el otro está activo

Comment: gracias @Padron Rocha por responder!, podrías mostrarlo con código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `val` aplica al objeto de jQuery como tal, pero aquí lo estás intentando aplicar a un  string (específicamente, al string de búsqueda con el que el operador `$(...)` genera un objeto de jQuery). Lo que el mensaje de error dice, en esencia, es que los strings no contienen ningún método llamado `val`.

Solo cambia la definición de `option` por la siguiente.

```
var option = $("input:radio[name='option']:checked").val();
```

Comment: gracias me sirvió tu resolucion!